# laptop not responding when unplugging external monitor

Tags: 16.04, screen, monitor

When I am working on my laptop, I turn its screen down to use an external monitor. When I am unplugging my laptop from the docking station in this situation, it stops responding (the screen of the computer stays black, and plugging it again is not changing anything... I have to hard restart it.).

However, if I am unplugging my Laptor from the docking station with its screen turned on, it continues to work fine.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this bug?

I am using a lenovo Thinkpad T480s and Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks

Comment: Dies the dicking station have DVI or HDMI monitor attached? How are you turning odd the internal monitor noe?

Comment: The external monitor is connected through a DisplayPort.
And I am turning off the laptop monitor using Ubuntu's Display window.